# jQuery Cycle, "after" option *just* before fx transition

Tags: jquery-cycle

I'm using fx: 'fade'
All working dandy, however I need to call a function *before* the actual fade in.

I've been playing around with the options **before** and **after** but **before** triggers to early and **after** too late.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this exact question.